# How to execute same functions using different parameters in a loop whenever a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following function:

(The array contains HTML DOM elements created by js)

```
function run(box,pos) {
      setInterval(() => {
        i = pos[0]

        if (i > box.length - 1) {
          i = 0
          box[box.length - 1].classList.remove('color')
        }

        if (i > 0) {
          box[i - 1].classList.remove('color')
        }


        box[i].classList.add('color')
        i++

        pos.unshift(i)
        pos.pop()
        console.log(pos)

      }, 500)
    }
```

There are three arrays (box) and three positions(pos) as parameters.

The first runs default at the beginning then on pressing a button I want it to stop and run the same function with second parameters and again on pressing the button with third parameters and after that when button is pressed the function should start with the first parameters as a loop.

There's only one button.

Comment: Please add the necessary HTML and arrays to reproduce the problem

Comment: Since you mentioned "a loop", does that refer to the setInterval function above? More often than not, you'd like to "stop" a function using `return` or `break` instead of a button. Or in this case, clearInterval might help https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: You need to return the return value of `setInterval` and pass it to `clearInterval` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval